# How to protect a system app's data from factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, restore, system-apps

Is it possible to protect a system app's data from factory reset?

For example: my phone is rooted. I choose to move the Tasker app as a system app. I want all the Profiles, Tasks, Scenes and settings to remain on my phone even after factory data reset. Is that possible? Is it possible to preserve the data of the app?

Comment: You can back up system settings using Titanium backup and restore them

Comment: Though I haven't tried converting user app to system app and backing/ restoring

Comment: yeah, but the data doesnt remain, when doing factory reset. I mean, let say for example email app, is there anyway that even factory reset the registered email will remain? perhaps moving the data to somewhere untouchable during reset?

Comment: Not sure of that...never tried:)

Comment: Whole app is restored if you backup the app data from /data/data/ or /data/user/ID/ and /sdcard/Android/data/ after reinstalling app or after factory reset. But you need to set the new app UID as well on all files and directories related to that app.